# Em uma activity, abre primeiramente o método onCreate ou o construtor da classe?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, construtor

Em um cenário onde você tem uma activity com um construtor (público, claro) e o método onCreate o qual faz parte do seu ciclo de vida. Qual dos dois será executado primeiro?

Comment: Não use o construtor da classe Activity. Tudo o que acha que deve/pode ser feito no construtor faça-o no `onCreate()`

Comment: mas respondendo a pergunta..
Segundo o siclo d vida do android, sera primeiro realizado o que esta no onCreate.

Comment: @Edumachdo O construtor é sempre chamado primeiro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pense assim, se um construtor é o primeiro "método" a ser executado, antes dos outros (mesmo se lá houver o método main, no caso do JAVA), então obviamente, o construtor será executado antes mesmo do onCreate().

Espero ter ajudado!